# What is compatible with Ultrabay?

Tags: graphics-card, lenovo-laptop

I'm considering buying a [Lenovo IdeaPad Y500](http://www.lenovo.com/products/us/laptop/ideapad/y-series/y500/).
Now, it has an [Ultrabay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenovo_UltraBay).
I'm confused which Ultrabay it has, and which GPU it can support.
Is it limited to:
1.   NVIDIA GT650M (the one in the laptop) or
2.  any NVIDIA GPU or
3. any GPU

Comment: What does Ultrabay and a GPU have to do with one another?

Comment: The Ultrabay accepts a secondary GPU because of the SLI structure.

Comment: @Ramhound: SLI via Ultrabay is a new concept for me too, but perhaps he's right? That page he linked to clearly states "Ultrabay: an interchangeable bay that can be instantly swapped out for dual graphics capability, increased storage space or an additional fan for cooling". Further, the [Tech Specs page](http://www.lenovo.com/products/us/tech-specs/laptop/ideapad/y-series/y500/) says "Optional **SLI Bay Graphics**". Can't just dismiss the suggestion outright, must be *something* to it...

Comment: But Lenovo **advertises** that the Y500 can accept a secondary GPU instead of the DVD writer for extra performance.

Comment: Looking at the manual I am indeed correct.  Lenovo sells the removable graphics card, this is not your typical mobile graphics card ( its likely pci-express ), you can order it through their store.  Page 16 of the manual has more information ( not a great deal more of course ).

Comment: @Ramhound I don't own it yet, could you post an answer and maybe include a scan or a copy of the digital version?

Comment: @Siddhartha - The manual is on Lenovo's website. I have said nothing I believe to be worthy of answer. I am certainly not going to open myself to another answer that gets downvoted without any reason. **Feel free to answer your own question**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ordered a Lenovo Y500 and separately bought the Ultrabay graphics. I received a GT650M removable graphics card that wasn't compatible with my GT750M. You need to have the same GPU in your ultrabay as in your computer.

Comment: Did you finally find a GT 750M ultrabay? I have recently purchased Y500 and looking for another graphics card. But, Lenovo says they are out of stock and told me to check back 1 week later.

Comment: I bought Y500 with two GT650M. One is on board, and one is in bay. Everything is fine with SLI, games are working great! (FullHD with highest details -> CPU = i7, 16GB RAM)

Comment: But can the principal GPU be replaced or canceled?